# slow ubuntu 18.4 vm in openstack

Tags: performance, graphics, virtual-machine, openstack

I am completely new to openstack. I am having some problem. Googling about it didn't help me. I am doing a project on implementing a private cloud using Openstack.

I have deployed multinode openstack (xena) on centos 8 stream (one controller and two compute nodes).

windows vms work normally but when i installed ubuntu 18.4 vm ,it work slowly specially the graphic is so slow. any solutions please and thank you

Comment: Have you tried to use a different render setting, like XRender? In KDE there's a setting in the display section called "Compositor". Try switching that, for me XRender works fine on a openSUSE Leap VM. I don't know which options you have in Ubuntu. Or what else is slow in that VM? Do you see anything suspicious in `top` or `vmstat` which could lead to other causes? Are the VMs on different storage backends within your cloud?

Comment: i have tried to use all the render setting available in ubuntu but graphics still slow especially when i play video it lags a lot .
i didn't find any unusual thing when using top or vmstat
thank you @eblock